# How to set default font family in React Native CLI in tailwind css?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

How can I apply a custom font globally in my React native CLI project while using tailwind css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: Adding Custom font as default utility class

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins&display=swap");
```

Whereby

```
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <section className="text-gray-600 body-font font-poppins">
      ...
    </section>
  );
}
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: [
    "./pages/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
    "./components/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
  ],
  theme: {
    extend:
    {
      fontFamily: {
        'poppins': ['Poppins', 'sans-serif']
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

2: Alternative Additional utility class

```
/* In your tailwind.config.js */

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    // Some useful comment
    fontFamily: {
      'nunito': ['nunito', 'sans-serif'],
      'MyFont': ['"My Font"', 'serif'] // Ensure fonts with spaces have " " surrounding it.
    },
  },
}
```

Usage

```
/* Generated by Tailwind CSS in your css file */

.font-nunito {
  font-family: nunito, sans-serif;
}

.font-MyFont {
  font-family: "My Font", serif;
}
```

Source:

- [1 logrocket](https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-custom-fonts-tailwind-css/).
- [2 tailwindtoolbox](https://www.tailwindtoolbox.com/guides/adding-fonts-to-tailwind-css)